# build a copy association in rails using this sql search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The goal is to replicate a table that the sql command below uses.

**SQL command:**

> SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "products_promotion_rules" ON "products"."id" = "products_promotion_rules"."product_id" WHERE "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products_promotion_rules"."promotion_rule_id" = $1

**My Rails association looks like this:**

```
class Product
  has_many :product_promotion_rules, class_name: 'ProductPromotionRule'
  has_many :promotion_rules, through: :product_promotion_rules
end 

class ProductPromotionRule
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :promotion_rule
end

class PromotionRule
   has_many :product_promotion_rules, class_name: 'ProductPromotionRule', join_table: 'products_promotion_rules', foreign_key: :promotion_rule_id
   has_many :products, through: :product_promotion_rules
   belongs_to :promotion 
end

class Promotion
   has_many :promotion_rules
end
```

I've tried using the above rails association, but I get an error that that product_promotion_rules table doesn't exist, I also get another error that says that `Promotion::Rules::ProductValue::ProductPromotionRule is an uninitialized constant`.

Comment: you want `ProductsPromotionRule` to get a table name of `products_promotion_rules`.  You'd need to update the association names

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to reproduce [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). That infers the presence of your `products_promotion_rules` table, and you don't need the `ProductPromotionRule` model, only `Product` and `PromotionRule`:

```
class Product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :promotion_rules
end

class PromotionRule
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

It looks like your schema is already in place, and should match this:

```
   Table "public.products"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer |

Table "public.promotion_rules"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer |

 Table "public.products_promotion_rules"
      Column       |  Type   | Modifiers
-------------------+---------+-----------
 product_id        | integer |
 promotion_rule_id | integer |
```

Comment: I have an error where Promotion_rules_rules does not exist when I implement that.